Is it okay to raise the output voltage of a 5v charger to charge a laptop battery whose charger supplied 15v (with a step up module)
I have a small 5v 2A charger, I would like to charge and use a laptop battery(for projects) which the laptop it belongs to is destroyed beyond repair, so I can't charge it in the laptop and the charger is not available locally.
The original charger supplied 15V 4A to the laptop to charge the battery.
The battery's output voltage is 10.8V.
Can I simply step up the voltage of my 5V charger to 15V and charge the battery by connecting to the positive and negative pins?

No, it is not OK.
You are forgetting that the 15V power supply is just a power supply.
You cannot connect 15V directly to a battery.
The battery charger is in the laptop, between the 15V supply and 10.8V battery.
The battery is likely a 3S lithium pack if it is rated 3.6V per cell. Generally, lithium cells are charged to something like 4.2V per cell.

You are forgetting to calculate power.

15 V × 4 A = 60 W
5 V × 2 A = 10 W

You would be way short of power before you consider the losses of your voltage step-up converter. Remember that when you step up the voltage from a 2 A max supply, the output will be 2 A / step-up-ratio. In your case you are hoping to step up by a factor of five so the max output at 100% step-up efficiency would be 0.4 A which is one tenth of that required by the laptop.

Yea, it is pretty brutal. But that means I should be able to charge the battery in around 10x the time, right?

@DanielAlemu No, because you will likely damage the boost converter if you connect it to a battery without battery charging circuit between the boost output and battery.

@justme hey thanks for the answer and comment, really appreciate it, :-) I failed to mention on the post that the batter does have a battery management system (BMS) on it with 9 pins for various types of data reading of the battery. Is this the "charger inside the laptop" that You mentioned in your answer. And in light of knowing its presence, would your answer be different, or is it still not ok?

@DanielAlemu A BMS manages the battery cell balance and protects it from overvoltage, overcurrent, overcharge, undervoltage and overdischarge. A charger charges the battery safely. So a BMS is not a charger. 15V on battery damages it; unless the BMS detects the overvoltage and cuts the pack off.

There is often a third wire on the chargers (co-axial ones often have different contacts on the inner and outer sleeves) and the third wire is used by the laptop to determine how much current it can safely draw. Without correct negotiation it may not charge at all.
